# Validation of object Names to set UILabel text name on a date picker

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I need to find a good way to validate the car names downloaded from a site. The car types are download and displayed on a date picker which allows your to choose the car type. Since there are only two car types I want to validate the c.name of the car in each row created which are two and set a string value I will code to display on the picker.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    Car *c = _downloadedCArss[row];

    UILabel* car = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,thePickerView.frame.size.width, 60)];
    car.text = v.name;
    car.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return car;
}
```

Im thinking of a If (*c.name = "BlackCar" then you will equal "YES" if thats not your name then you equal "NO"*)

but then I would need to create a new object a subclass to display on the `UILable*` car correct?

for example

`if v.name is "BlackCar"` you are now `c.name1` and your value is `"YES"` if not then you are `c.name1` and your value is `"NO"` I would have to return the updated value for the new object `c.name1` and make the `UILable*` car `car.text = c.name1;` correct? Im really stuck as how to write that if statement on the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pas information using `NSString` and make a method like:

```
if (c.name isEqualToString:@"BlackCar"){
      car.text = @"YES";
} else {
      car.text = @"NO";
}
```

Maybe if I understand what you want to do.

Hope this help you.